# Maven + Eclipse: how to disable fetch of all versions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a set of plugins made with eclipse and I'm using maven to compile them all together. The final build works, however, I have an annoying problem when doing the $mvn install$: maven download all the latest versions of eclipse, xtext, xtend plugins

A very short log is the following

```
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars [INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/ (0B at 0B/s) 
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201506241002/ (0B at 0B/s) 
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201510021000/ (0B at 0B/s) 
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201602261000/ (0B at 0B/s)
```

Basically, this makes the build very slow....

The interested master pom part is set like this

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tycho-version>0.23.0</tycho-version>
        <eclipse-repository>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars</eclipse-repository>
        <xtext-repository>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases</xtext-repository>
        <orcc-repository>http://www.turnus.co/addons/orcc/</orcc-repository>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mars</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${eclipse-repository}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>orcc</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${orcc-repository}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>xtext</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${xtext-repository}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/src-gen</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- clean output directories -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>auto-clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src-gen</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Do you know how I can modify it and speed-up the process?

Thanks!

S.

Comment: Did you consider to use version specific repos instead of the composite ones. Use a tool like p2browser or follow the compositeContent.xml|jar files manually

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hint:

Maven supports the `-o` or `--offline` options in which case it only uses locally cached artifacts. You can use this for quicker local builds. Your integration build can (and should) still use the actual online p2 repository.

If you want to more generally address the loading time as well, I see two options:

1. The `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars/` repository is a composite repository. This means that it just contains a bunch of pointers to other p2 repositories. This is why it contacts and downloads all the other `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/${timestamp}/` repositories. If you know you only want the latest Mars release, you could try to directly add the `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201602261000/` instead of the composite repository.
2. You could build your own p2 repository containing exactly what you need and store this on a local server for maven to use that. The b3 aggregator (https://www.eclipse.org/b3/) is a good tool to aggregate and build consistent custom p2 update sites.

Comment: In addition to Stefan Winklers answer you should inspect the settings.xml in .m2 folder. There you can find `<updatePolicy></updatePolicy>`.
It seems that this has the value "always" cause by default this value is meant to be daily...